# Any way to set value for a particular cookie in selenium?

Tags: cookies, selenium-webdriver

I've tried using driver.manage().getCookies().add(new Cookie("cookie-name","cookie-value")); 
But that didnt set the value of the Cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work.

```
driver.get(yourAppUrl);  //this statement must execute before you set cookies.
Cookie newCookie= new Cookie(name, value);
driver.manage().addCookie(newCookie);
```

Comment: It didnt really work Prateek. I am using the above code for an AndroidDriver. Here are the logs:

Comment: Didnt work,using the above code for AndroidDriver. Logs: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An error occurred (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{platform=ANDROID, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=43.0.2357.93, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true}]

Comment: can you show me the code you are using or the Github link of repository?

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.4");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");                                                                                              driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
Cookie c = new Cookie("abRand", "1");
driver.manage().addCookie(c);

Comment: It is throwing error of the log shared above in the line: driver.manage().addCookie(c); Am i missing adding some dependency or capability?

Comment: may be, I've come up with the solution, Can you please try to set the cookie after, once you have called  **driver.get** method to visit the App Url.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Can you please try it out quickly and let me know if it again cries.

Comment: Thanks Prateek. It works, my bad that I was trying to set a cookie before opening the webpage. My aim is to set the value of an existing cookie to 1, this one creates a new cookie of the same name and its value is not being considered. I also tried Cookie ck=driver.manage().getCookieNamed("abRand"); and ck.getValue(); but got a null pointer exception in the second line. I dont see any method named setValue() too. Any suggestion on how value of the existing cookie can be set?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best solution or not, you could delete the existing cookie and then add a new one with same **key**. Probably you'd like to read more about cookies and check if they are immutable objects.

and please don't forget to upvote my answer, so it can help other people as well.

Comment: Cool Prateek, will try that. I tried upvoting on day 1 only, it says: "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly-displayed post score"

Comment: Apologies, I used the wrong word *UPVOTE*, I should have asked to **ACCEPT** my answer by clicking on the _Right Tick_ below the upvote and downvote button.